# Is it possible to hack my encrypted session and hijack the session by electromagnetic waves?

Tags: macos, risk

I'm concerned about microwave technologies nowadays and suspicious matter happend.

So, I have several questions. Could you tell me about my question in below if you know.

Question:

1. Is it possible to hack my encrypted session such SSL/TLS and
   hijack (duplicate) the session by electromagnetic waves?
2. What will be possible to grab my data from the encrypted session such Google
   Account(Gmail)?
3. What will a good solution for the authentication such Google Account?
4. Is PKCS type of token available to protect my session and logon my Mac?
5. Is it possible to log about changes on my Mac by microwaves?
6. Are there any way to protect my Mac(Developoment data) from TEMPST?
7. How can I protect me from microwaves.

Sorry I don't know how TEMPEST like technology works. So, I would like to know about it.

Browser: Chrome (latest)
OS: OSX Mavericks
MacBook Air

Comment: @TheRookierLearner OP isn't crazy, his fears (although unnecessary) are somewhat substantiated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_%28codename%29 It's just that this question is very broad.

Comment: My bad! Deleted my comment.

Comment: Frankly, you should be much more worried about other attack vectors (as stated at the end of my answer), but if you feel like making #2 and #4 more comprehensible, so that I can understand what you're asking, I'd be willing to update my answer to attempt to answer them.

Comment: You have tried to ask too much here. Questions 2 to 5 need to be split out as separate questions. 6 and 7 can be made into one question. Question 1 is not a question.

Comment: @user3171796 : Maybe if you are using a very old CRT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to preface my answer with this:

The real world is not like the movies - it's vastly easier to hide a camera somewhere and point it at your screen, or pick the lock on your door and upload a virus to your laptop, or copy the hard drive than it is to sit in a van down the street and read stray EM waves from your monitor... so if someone wants to spy on you, they'll only use Van Eck snooping if they can't spy on you an easier way - and there's almost always an easier way to do it than Van Eck snooping.

> 1) Is it possible to hack my encrypted session such SSL/TLS and hijack (duplicate) the session by electromagnetic waves?

No.  SSL/TLS and other encrypted protocols implement counter-measures to prevent this type of attack, which is properly called a [replay attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack).

> 3) What will a good solution for the authentication such Google Account?

[Google offers a free 2 factor authentication option to protect your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744?hl=en).  Use it.

> 5) Is it possible to log about changes on my Mac by microwaves?

Not... unless you're using your Mac to cook food.  I think what you want to ask about is [Van Eck snooping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Eck_phreaking).  And yes, there are plenty of ways to prevent it.

Truly paranoid or security-conscious people and organizations will go so far as to install wire mesh in their walls and special films on their windows to block electromagnetic waves and prevent this type of snooping.  Alternately, you can use similar shielding on the electronics themselves.  The other countermeasure involves altering the signal in ways that can't be perceived by human vision, but make it much more difficult to reverse engineer the signal back into an image.

> 6) Are there any way to protect my Mac(Developoment data) from TEMPST?

[Well, since TEMPEST covers both protecting equipment against Van Eck snooping, and performing Van Eck snooping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_%28codename%29), you would simply implement the countermeasures indicated in the standard, or other standards based on it... such as the USAF standards linked below.

[Instruction AFI 33-203 Vol 1, Emission Security](http://www.e-publishing.af.mil/shared/media/epubs/AFI33-203V1.pdf)

[Instruction AFI 33-203 Vol 3, EMSEC Countermeasures Reviews](http://www.e-publishing.af.mil/shared/media/epubs/AFI33-203V3.pdf)

[Instruction AFI 33-201 Vol 8, Protected Distributed Systems](http://www.e-publishing.af.mil/shared/media/epubs/AFI33-201V8.pdf)

> 7) How can I protect me from microwaves.

The easiest way to protect yourself from microwaves, would be to wrap yourself in aluminum foil.  Assuming you mean Van Eck snooping... well, I've answered that above.

Frankly, you should probably be much more worried about someone placing a small, hidden camera somewhere to view your screen, installing a keylogger on your laptop, or cloning your hard drive than you should be of Van Eck snooping, but I digress.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail answer and it's helped me a lot. I face suspicious matter such there are two cup 30 centimeters distant. The one of them has many bubles inside. but the other one has no buble. and  there is no affected equipment and electrical device on my desk.

Comment: @user3171796 whilst clearly you are trolling I suggest this talk given my Melissa Elliott at last years Defcon titled "noise floor": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_g9yUiAHiFo in adition to the detail HopelessN00b has provided ... as well as perhaps a tinfoil hat, straight jacket and some powerful sedatives for the protection of those around you.

Comment: @Oneiroi, Thank you for the information except for sedatives which makes everybody's life goes bad. I have  setup my Mac with 3rd party's firewall to protect even outbound packet and application runs also. But my Mac setting has changed looks via microwaves. Now My Mac is  getting hot somehow. It's very strange.